# Restricting php pdo execute() to running just the first sql statement

Tags: php, sql, pdo

Is there a way to restrict php pdo execute() to run just the first sql statement?

For instance running

`SELECT * FROM customer;DROP TABLE invoice`

will return all customers but it will also delete the invoice table.

I have a situation where I need a whole SQL statement from a user but it must be a SELECT and nothing additional.

My example is just one of many that could be maliciously entered. It might include additional DROP, UPDATE, DELETE statements etc.

A prepared statement will simply replace ?s with values. It will not stop dangerous SQL statemets being passed to it.

This would not be a problem if there was a way to restrict php pdo execute() to run just the first sql statement?

Comment: Why would you put that statement in there if you don't require it? And if you're worried about injection then Prepared statements in PDO will themselves take care of that

Comment: if you specifically want to delete if your query contains drop query, and if you have that query in some variable then `preg_replace("/(.*?)DROP(.*)/", "$1", "SELECT * FROM customer;DROP TABLE invoice
");` will delete drop query if it's present in that query

Comment: @user790454 - That can fail if selecting a substring or inserting a substring that contains the word drop.

Comment: yes,then we can replace drop with ;

Comment: My example is just one of many that could be maliciously entered. It might be DROP, UPDATE, DELETE.@Hanky 웃 Panky how do I make this a prepared statement as I am not actually replacing ?s with values?

Comment: I like the approach suggested in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13064261/622391) to the marked duplicate - run the query with a user account which only has `SELECT` privileges.

Comment: @Simon MᶜKenzie - I have places in the same application that needs to run DELETES and APPENDS and INSERTS, places the user cannot access. Could the answer to my original question simply be No?

Comment: Why are people insisting that this question has already been asked?

Comment: @user1397366, perhaps running code supplied by the user vs. your own "clean" code justifies running the user code in a more locked-down environment (i.e. via a different account). After all, that's why roles exist. As to your actual question, doesn't `explode(';',sql)[0]` get rid of all subsequent statements (assuming no semicolons in strings)?

Comment: I'll tell you why. Imagine you are gong to build a car. And then comes along asking "how to make square wheels for a car"? Everyone would point you out to the question where construction of round wheels is explained. The problem with programming is that everyone taking it as a picnic. Everything can be done and anyone can make everything. No rules, no knowledge, no restrictions. Just a free flow of imagination required. In reality a car won't go on square wheels. In reality you should not receive no raw SQL from a user, unless you are definitely and positively know what are you doing.

Comment: @Your Common Sense Poor analogy (still not answering the question).

Answer (score 0):

IF your trying to prevent SQL injection, prepare statements can handle it.

you can use something like this to prevent SQL injection

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=? AND name=?");
$stmt->bindValue(1, $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindValue(2, $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but I am not actually replacing ?s with values. It is a case where I need to accept an sql string from the user and not just values, it must be a SELECT statement and may do damage to the system otherwise.

Comment: in that case you would need Keyword blacklist, or simply change the DB prevellage so that its not possible to drop table;